# Why doesn't anything appear on my web page when I use Instagram API?

Tags: api, instagram

I'm trying to use Instagram API on my web page to get user information, but when I use the API, I see only a blank page.

My code was working a few days ago, what might the problem be?

```
require_once 'instagram.class.php';
$instagram = new Instagram('xxx');
$tag = 'tag';
$media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);
$limit = 50;
foreach(array_slice($media->data, 0, $limit) as $data)
{

    $image = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
    $avatar = $data->user->profile_picture;
    $username = $data->user->username;

     if ($image <> '') { 
      $sqlMy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE image='$image'");
          $sorgula = mysql_num_rows($sqlMy);
          if($sorgula=="0")
       {

    $yaz2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id,image,avatar,username) VALUES ('','$image','$avatar','$username')");
        }
}
}
```